# Electron , collision , current , dual nature

Tags: electrical-engineering

My question is regarding fundemantal concept.
I am good in kcl and kvl delta to y resistor rcl and rl circuits machines etc  but as i read drift velocity i get so many questions.

We are reading since childhood that electron loose their energy while collision with neighbour electron or collision with nucleus during heat n electric flow but if electron collides with proton i means how its possible electron is in valence shel so while going towards nucleus it must realses all spectrum energy

Second electron have dual nature so how this collision can be understood through wave nature.

Thirdly lets observe a wire have resistor of some specific value but if i change its value did the current change instantly or it takes times because as i change resistor the drift velocity also changes.

Comment: The electrons in metals that are conducting electricity are not in valence shells but in a continuous conduction band. The existence of these bands is predicted correctly by quantum mechanics. The energy these electrons  lose is thermalized into phonons, i.e. they generate heat.

Comment: -CuriousOne ok but look i have resistor of some value and i apply electric field so how i get current value instantly i mean drift vocity is very low

Comment: You have to include the propagation of electromagnetic waves around the resistor into the calculation (i.e. the displacement current and the skin effect) if you want to understand the actual velocity of electric propagation. That the energy is propagated by electrons is the wrong mental model. The electrons in metals cause a boundary condition for the electric field, which "binds" the electromagnetic wave to the conductor, but they are not responsible for the energy transfer.

Comment: I dont know why quantum model is not in my course of electrical engineering undergrad...

Comment: It takes an entire class in quantum mechanics and one class in solid state physics to cover the mechanisms that are important in solids (assuming that you know electrodynamics, already). I have seen engineering classes that tried to do all of this "on the go" in a few weeks and the engineers didn't understand a thing and were desperately asking the physics students for help.

Comment: So can i have a chance of geting physicst after this engineering.

Comment: That's up to you. If you are interested in physics you can study it in detail, if you wish.

Comment: Can you please refer me some books or lectures as begineer of all of these concepts.

Comment: We don't like to give resource recommendations around here. It won't help you much, either. Physics is not exactly something that is suitable for self-study, unless you are exceptionally gifted. If you want to understand physics, I would suggest you take the physics classes at your university.